# colour range of ggfluctuation in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to use two heatmaps with the `ggfluctuation` in  `ggplot2`. The two tables for the heatmaps have the different max value (supposing 0.8 and 0.9). In order to make them comparable, so I want to know how to make their colors both varying from 0 to 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use `ggfluctuation`; it is deprecated. The effect you desire can be achieved using `geom_tile()` as below. If you have multiple plots, create one colour scale and apply it to each plot in turn:

```
library("ggplot2")

# creat variable to flag whether diamond size is below mean
diamonds$small <- diamonds$carat < mean(diamonds$carat)

# create table suitable for plotting, with facets by size
d2 <- data.frame(table(diamonds$cut, diamonds$color, diamonds$small))
names(d2) <- c("cut", "color", "size", "freq")

# create colour scale
c.scale <- scale_fill_gradient(low = "white", 
                               high = "steelblue",
                               limits=c(min(d2$freq),
                                        max(d2$freq)))

# apply the same scale to different plots
p1 <- ggplot(d2[which(d2$size == TRUE),], aes(cut, color)) + 
    geom_tile(aes(fill = freq), colour="white") 

p1 + c.scale

p2 <- ggplot(d2[which(d2$size == FALSE),], aes(cut, color)) + 
    geom_tile(aes(fill = freq), colour="white") 

p2 + c.scale
```

### Result: Two plots

#### Plot `p1`

[image: plot p1]

#### Plot `p2`

[image: plot p2]

Comment: Thanks first and a further question, in fact I have so many heatmaps like this, I will store them in different files. Is't possible to control the color range to make compare them convenient in separative file.